# Elixir - Append to tuple in various if clauses, but then tuple keeps getting reset to blank

Tags: elixir, ecto

This code used to work, being able to put custom messages inside `messages` depending on the various clauses and send those messages back to the front end.

I updated Elixir. Now `messages` is always `{}` when it gets sent back to the frontend. What do I have to do to get this old code to append messages to `messages` now? It'll append them and I'll inspect right after and they will be there. But then at the end, nothing is in there.

All my other code still works, it's just `messages` is never returning anything to the front end anymore because it becomes empty by the end of the function. It's like the variable scope inside the iff isn't the same, and its a whole different variable or something.

```
defmodule Api.Controllers.PutProductIsVegan do 
  import Api.UserProduct
  alias Api.UserProduct, as: UserProduct
  import Ecto.Query
  import Api.Repo
  import Plug.Conn

  def parse_elem("true"),  do: true
  def parse_elem("false"), do: false

  def put_product_is_vegan(conn) do
    messages = {}
    db_user_product = %{}
    product = Api.Product |> Api.Repo.get(conn.query_params["p_id"])
    vegan_count = product.vegan_count
    not_vegan_count = product.not_vegan_count
    confirm = parse_elem(conn.body_params["confirm"])
    report = parse_elem(conn.body_params["report"])
    IO.inspect(confirm, label: "confirm")
    IO.inspect(report, label: "report")
    uid = conn.query_params["u_id"]
    pid = conn.query_params["p_id"]
    IO.inspect(uid, label: "confirm")
    IO.inspect(pid, label: "report")

    user_product = (from up in Api.UserProduct,
    where: up.u_id == ^uid,
    where: up.p_id == ^pid)
    |> Api.Repo.one
    IO.inspect(user_product)

    if !user_product do
      IO.puts("insert user product")
      UserProduct.insert_user_product(conn, %{
      p_id: String.to_integer(pid), 
      u_id: uid, 
      voted_not_vegan: report,
      voted_vegan: confirm
      })
    end

    user_product = (from up in Api.UserProduct,
    where: up.u_id == ^uid,
    where: up.p_id == ^pid)
    |> Api.Repo.one
    IO.inspect(user_product)

    if !user_product.voted_not_vegan && report do
      IO.puts("add 1 to product.not_vegan_count")
      changeset = Api.Product.changeset(
        product, %{:not_vegan_count => not_vegan_count + 1}
      )
      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
        {:ok, product} -> 
          messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
        {:error, changeset} -> 
          messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
      IO.puts("set up.voted_not_vegan to true")
      changeset = Api.UserProduct.changeset(
        user_product, %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
      )
      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
    end

    if !user_product.voted_vegan && confirm do
      IO.puts("add 1 to product.vegan_count")
        changeset = Api.Product.changeset(
          product, %{:vegan_count => vegan_count + 1}
        )
        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
        end
      IO.puts("set up.voted_vegan to true") 
      IO.inspect (user_product)
      changeset = Api.UserProduct.changeset(
        user_product, %{:voted_vegan => true}
      )

      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> 
            messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
    end

    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
          successs: "success",
          errors: Tuple.to_list(messages)
      }))
  end
end
```

EDIT

From Adams answer I have done this, but the `messages` is still blank at the end:

```
defmodule Api.Controllers.PutProductIsVegan do 
  import Api.UserProduct
  alias Api.UserProduct, as: UserProduct
  import Ecto.Query
  import Api.Repo
  import Plug.Conn

  def parse_elem("true"),  do: true
  def parse_elem("false"), do: false

  def put_product_is_vegan(conn) do
    messages = {}
    db_user_product = %{}
    product = Api.Product |> Api.Repo.get(conn.query_params["p_id"])
    vegan_count = product.vegan_count
    not_vegan_count = product.not_vegan_count
    confirm = parse_elem(conn.body_params["confirm"])
    report = parse_elem(conn.body_params["report"])
    IO.inspect(confirm, label: "confirm")
    IO.inspect(report, label: "report")
    uid = conn.query_params["u_id"]
    pid = conn.query_params["p_id"]
    IO.inspect(uid, label: "confirm")
    IO.inspect(pid, label: "report")

    user_product = (from up in Api.UserProduct,
    where: up.u_id == ^uid,
    where: up.p_id == ^pid)
    |> Api.Repo.one
    IO.inspect(user_product)

    if !user_product do
      IO.puts("insert user product")
      UserProduct.insert_user_product(conn, %{
      p_id: String.to_integer(pid), 
      u_id: uid, 
      voted_not_vegan: report,
      voted_vegan: confirm
      })
    end

    user_product = (from up in Api.UserProduct,
    where: up.u_id == ^uid,
    where: up.p_id == ^pid)
    |> Api.Repo.one
    IO.inspect(user_product)

    if user_product.voted_not_vegan && report do
      messages = Tuple.append(messages, "You have already reported this product")
    end

    if !user_product.voted_not_vegan && report do
      IO.puts("add 1 to product.not_vegan_count")
      changeset = Api.Product.changeset(
        product, %{:not_vegan_count => not_vegan_count + 1}
      )
      messages =
      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
        {:ok, product} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
        {:error, changeset} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
      IO.puts("set up.voted_not_vegan to true")
      changeset = Api.UserProduct.changeset(
        user_product, %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
      )
      messages =
      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
    end

    if !user_product.voted_vegan && confirm do
      IO.puts("add 1 to product.vegan_count")
        changeset = Api.Product.changeset(
          product, %{:vegan_count => vegan_count + 1}
        )
        messages =
        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
        end
      IO.puts("set up.voted_vegan to true") 
      IO.inspect (user_product)
      changeset = Api.UserProduct.changeset(
        user_product, %{:voted_vegan => true}
      )

      messages =
      case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
          {:error, changeset} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
      end
    end

    IO.inspect(messages) # this is {}

    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
          successs: "success",
          errors: Tuple.to_list(messages)
      }))
  end
end
```

Comment: that's pretty messy

Comment: do you have `IO.puts` outputs somewhere? It is possible none of the Tuple.appends are actually executed (?). It is hard to say without having your data. I also have no idea why you use Tuples here. You can simply use lists with the same exact effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in statements like this:

```elixir
case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
  {:ok, product} -> 
    messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
  {:error, changeset} -> 
    messages = Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
end
```

Although you are assigning to `messages`, that is scoped to inside the case statement. You're effectively appending to the tuple, assigning that to a new scoped variable that also happens to be called `messages`, then discarding it. Then you're using the original declaration of `messages = {}` when you do `Tuple.to_list(messages)`.

You should be able to fix it by assigning the result of the case statement to `messages`:

```elixir
messages =
  case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, product} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product updated")
    {:error, changeset} -> Tuple.append(messages, "Product not updated")
  end
```

Unfortunately it looks like you need a lot of restructuring, because the code is using a mutable coding style in an immutable language. If you wanted to restructure, you could do something like this:

Define a function that accepts a list of messages, and conditionally adds a new message:

```elixir
def add_message_if(messages, message, true), do: [message | messages]
def add_message_if(messages, _message, false), do: messages
```

Then you can call it in a chain like this:

```elixir
messages =
[]
|> add_message_if("You have already reported this product", user_product.voted_not_vegan)
|> add_message_if("Product updated", !user_product.voted_not_vegan && updated?)
|> add_message_if("Product not updated", !user_product.voted_not_vegan && !updated?)
...
```

Then finally, `Enum.reverse(messages)`, because we were prepending the messages.

Comment: Thanks, `messages` is still blank. At the bottom of my question I have posted my updated code where I try your solution.

Comment: The problem cascades. The case statements are inside if statements, which causes the same problem to happen. You need to do the same thing around your if statements (convert the inner `block { messages = ...}` to `messages = block {}`).

Comment: I think when `messages = if false` causes messages to become `nil` because it doesn't enter the if block.

Comment: One hacky fix for that could be adding `else { messages }`... but it's probably better to just restructure the whole thing ;-)

Comment: That prints out `{"You have already reported this product"}` for me. Anyway, I think you are going down a dark path. I updated my answer to suggest an alternative strategy. See also Aleksei's answer.

Comment: Thanks. What does your second `add_message_if` do after the `do`? If the boolean is false it means don't add the message? 

I have used those 2 message functions elsewhere and got a function clause error on`add_message_if([], "Success! Reported not in shop", "false")`. Do you see what is wrong with the values that I passed into `add_message_if`?

Comment: That's correct, the 2nd clause just returns `messages` unmodified. I think your error is because you're passing the string `"false"` instead of the boolean `false` (without quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You should start with understanding that *everything* in *Elixir* is immutable. *Everything* means *everything*. The following code

```
foo = {}
if true, do: foo = Tuple.append(foo, :bar)
```

does not change the outer `foo` as you expected. That said, the initial assignment `messages = {}` makes zero sense and the wall if conditional statements are in fact all NOOPs.

Also, one should not use tuples to reduce, one should better [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) with a list accumulator and convert to tuple afterward, if the desired result type is a tuple. Somewhat like this:

```
actions = %{
  user_product.voted_not_vegan && report => fn messages ->
    ["You have already reported this product" | messages]
  end,

  !user_product.voted_not_vegan && report => fn messages ->
    IO.puts("add 1 to product.not_vegan_count")
    changesets = [
      Api.Product.changeset(
        product, %{not_vegan_count: not_vegan_count + 1}
      ),
      Api.UserProduct.changeset(
       user_product, %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
      )
    ]
    Enum.reduce(changesets, messages, fn 
      {:ok, _} -> ["Product updated" | messages]
      {:error, _} -> ["Product not updated" | messages]
    end)
  end,
  ...
}

actions
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  {true, reducer}, messages -> reducer.(messages)
  {false, _} -> messages 
end)
|> Enum.reverse()
|> List.to_tuple()
```

Here we build a map of `action_needed => action` in the first place and then reduce actions, applying the respective action if and only it’s needed.

Since we use `reduce`, we *keep the accumulator value between iterations*, unlike reassigning it wherever.

There is a rule of thumb: in 99% of cases in *Elixir* if you find yourself using a conditional, you are doing it plain wrong.